# Column To generate Flag Values for use in bitwise comparisons

Tags: sql-server, bitwise-comparison

We are in the process of creating a new application where various tables are used to hold enumerations.  Since the IDs in these tables will be used in bitwise comparisons, we'd like to ensure new rows inserted will automatically use the decimal number that corresponds to the next bit being "set".

For instance, if we had an alarm clock application, we might include a "Weekdays" table which could be used in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Weekdays
(
    WeekdayID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Weekdays PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , WeekdayName VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Weekdays
VALUES (1, 'Sunday')
    , (2, 'Monday')
    , (4, 'Tuesday')
    , (8, 'Wednesday')
    , (16, 'Thursday')
    , (32, 'Friday')
    , (64, 'Saturday');

CREATE TABLE dbo.AlarmsDefined
(
    AlarmID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_AlarmsDefined PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , Weekdays INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.AlarmsDefined (AlarmID, Weekdays)
VALUES (1, 50);

SELECT W.WeekdayName
FROM dbo.AlarmsDefined AD
    INNER JOIN dbo.Weekdays W ON (AD.Weekdays & W.WeekdayID) = W.WeekdayID
```

The results of the above `SELECT` query:

[image]

I'd like to be able to define the Weekdays table in the above example such that if we added another row to the table, the next `WeekdayID` would be automatically set as 128, which is the next decimal number that can be used in bitwise comparisons.

This of course can be accomplished by putting in the values by hand into the primary key column.

But is there a way to specify an automatically incrementing value which would adhere to the flag values? For example these would be the unique PK values generated:

```
ID
--
1
2
4
8
16
32
...
```

and the trigger would automatically look at the last value and generate the next in the sequence needed?

Comment: Do you want an exponential increment or just a static increment? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @John Increment, either can be used. Version is 2012. I don't expect more than 15 flags(?)/rows of data, but an upper limit depending on target column type would be understood.

Comment: Ignore the explanation at the top, but my answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89851/how-to-properly-increment-an-int-identity-in-sql-server-if-the-identity-incremen/89857#89857) to use a sequence object should be what you want.

Comment: @John I read the link to [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx) but it is unclear to me on how to do a `multiply` operation on the `INCREMENT BY <constant>` specification.

Comment: So you do want an exponential increment then?

Comment: @John Yes, I didn't believe incremental would work, but I didn't want to limit the answers if it was possible. The example, I believe, gives the best representation of the numbers needed and how they interact. Basically its `previous` `*` 2 starting at 1.

Answer (score 5):

I would use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL
    , val AS (POWER(2,id)) PERSISTED
    , CONSTRAINT pk_test PRIMARY KEY
        (
            val
        )
);
GO

INSERT #test DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 15

SELECT * FROM #test;
```

Comment: I am looking for the PK to have the `val` value in my table; can you change your example table to not have the `id` value? I understand its key to its processing and this is a good system, but my goal is to have only one column the `id` column with your `val` value. I sense this example is similar to creating a *Numbers* only table to do select programming processing with the static numbers.

Comment: @OmegaMan If you look closely you will see that `val` **is** the primary key.

Comment: Right it is ... I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The *ideal* way to be incrementing a primary key, as I noted in the comments, is to use the new `SEQUENCE` object in SQL 2012. It'll minimize the overhead of this generation process and is the best option in most cases.

However, if you truly have to have exponentially increasing keys, then using a trigger will work. This may be better served in a stored procedure using the same logic, but it's easier to demonstrate via a trigger as I don't have more information as to how these inserts are occurring in your system.

You can do an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger since it looks like this is a primary key and probably will be `NOT NULL` as a result:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_setPK]
ON [Table] INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @newID INT
        SET @newID = SELECT MAX(ID) * 2 FROM [Table]
        INSERT INTO [Table] 
            VALUES(@newID, Inserted.column1, Inserted.column2 ....)
    END
GO
```

or use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger if `NULL` isn't a concern (though it should be):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_setPK]
ON [Table] AFTER INSERT 
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET ID = MAX(ID) * 2 FROM [Table]
    END
GO
```

These aren't going to be ideal for scaling up, but should do the trick.